# Codeigniter dynamic page overriding controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, routes, overriding

I have a dynamic page called link (**from the db**) and I have a controller called link.Is there a way that I can stop them overriding each other?.  My routes seem to be over written too.

**Example:**

In my db I have a `url/slug` called `name` but I also have a controller called `name`.  How can I stop them overwriting each other?

Comment: Please explain the question in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve? It's better to avoid the name clash whenever possible.
You need to work with your routing rules. If I understand you right, you may need to dinamicaly change your routing rules to include all your slug options first. It should look like:

```
$route['url-slug-1'] = "page/article"
$route['url-slug-2'] = "page/article"
$route['name']       = "page/article" // this should not call your "name" controller
```

In 'page' controller's 'article' method you can find out the slug value by using URI class.